# How does ExpressJS determine if a requested resource is a "static" file?

Tags: express, jspm

I'm using JSPM to manage my client side dependencies and serving files using ExpressJS
My Directory structure is

- node_modules
- routes
- views
- app.js
- public
- - css
- - images
- - js
- - - main.js
- - jspm_packages
- - - system.js
- - - npm
- - - - angular2@2.0.0-beta.7.js

I have static route setup in my Express app.js as follows:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

As expected when I request for GET /jspm_packages/system.js
it serves the file correctly

however when I request GET /jspm_packages/npm/angular2@2.0.0-beta.7.js
It gives me a 404 - not found.

I suspect some of those special characters in the file name are messing up express from resolving the request as a "static" file and using the correct static route.

How can I test if express is marking the request as "static"?
How can I overwrite the express regex (or whatever mechanism) express is using to mark a request as "static"?
How can I write a custom middleware using my own regex and forward the request to static instead?

thanks.

Comment: Did you get chance to go through the answer?

Answer (score 3):

When working with express, you must make sure right middleware is registered in right order.

As per your question, `How does express identifies a resource as static?`, Actually express does not determine if its static or not, it does not even understand request types, what express does is execute proper middleware for given request.

When express receives a request, It goes and starts executing matching middleware in sequence until it runs out of them.

So in practice, you'll always register your static middleware first (just after request parsers and all), before your dynamic routes. Like shown below ...

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

//Register your static middleware
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//Other cool code

app.use('/', routes);
```

Now, request will first go through `express.static` middleware, if it does not find a matching file, it will call `next` internally and pass request to next middleware in chain.

Meaning, suppose you have a static file in `public` directory named `users` and you have a route named `routes.get('/users' ....`. Now when user requests `/users`, the request will first pass to `express.static` and if it finds `users` file (which it does in this case), our route that we registered using `routes.get` will never get called. Now if you do the same but just remove the file named `users` from the `public` folder, then `express.static` middleware won't be able to find a matching file and will pass request to next middleware in chain i.e. `routes.get(`/users' ...`

> Express does not assume or identify a resource as static by matching or using regular-expressions. If `express.static` middleware finds it, it will serve it else it will pass on the request to the next middleware in queue.

Though I was pretty sure, I tried to reproduce your issue, and I was served with the file with all the special characters in it, just as shown in following image.

[image]

Please reconfirm following:

1. Your `express.static` middleware gets registered first.
2. The resource you are trying to access exists, i.e. physical path exsists. (resource url are case insensitive, i.e. `/USERS` and `/users` both will match a file `/public/users` if it exists.
3. Make sure you don't have a typo.

If this does not resolve your issue, please share your app.js file, some content if you can't share all of it.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you need further assistance ... :)